# Allow cors in Flask api for d3.xhr

Tags: d3.js, flask, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm writing a simple Flask api that will serve data to a d3.js frontend and I am getting this error when I try to query for the data:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5000/data/sample_data. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

I am using the [flask-cors](http://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension for flask, even though I am querying from my own domain (localhost) so I thought that this shouldn't even count as "Cross-domain". Can anyone shed some light on why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you missing a `http://` in the URL by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs should have a valid schema for CORS to kick in. While Chrome's address bar can prefix the schema for URLs, most AJAX libraries (jQuery, d3, etc.) do not smartly do it before making the request.

Appending `http://` to the URL(s) should fix the problem.